# I've seen 達人and 名人used to indicate master or expert. What's the difference?

Tags: word-choice, usage, vocabulary

I'm not familiar with either word, but just looking at the characters, 達人 would seem to indicate 'accomplished' (ie an accomplished pianist). While 名人 seems more like 'renowned'. Is that a valid assessment?

Comment: 師匠　【ししょう】 and 名匠　【めいしょう】 are a couple more good words for master/expert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following:

> 達 as a kanji has the meaning "accomplish", "(to) reach"
>
> 名 as a kanji has the meaning "name" or "reputation"

Kanji compounds:

> 達成 : "achievement"
>
> 名高い : "famous, celebrated"
>
> 威名 : "fame, prestige"

And in Chinese, `名人(míng rén)` has no connotations of skill as far as I know, it simply means "famous person". `達人(dá rén)` however means "expert" and does not imply fame.

I would say your assessment is a reasonable one.

Comment: Nice answer, but I really don't think you should be using Chinese meanings when discussing Japanese nuances (words like 愛人 come to mind)...

Comment: I take Chinese as additional information to consider. I found comparing meanings to Chinese quite helpful in learning certain vocabulary. But one must be careful not to equate them, since there are sure to be differences as you mentioned.

Answer (score 5):

Both 達人 and 名人 are usually associated with skills in Japanese.

達人 means a person who has mastered everything about something by long-time experience.

名人 usually means a person who has excellent skills.  [Daijisen](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E5%90%8D%E4%BA%BA&dtype=0&dname=0na&stype=0) also lists another meaning “評判の高い人” (person who is spoken well of), but I think that the usage without connotation with high skills is rare.  [Daijirin](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E5%90%8D%E4%BA%BA&dtype=0&dname=0ss&stype=0) does not state the latter meaning.